# slide animation for navigation angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, ng-animate

I am new to angularjs and I am trying to implement sliding navigation between screens. I mean, slide/swipe the screen to go to the next page. I am followed this link
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/08/18/angularjs-animations-in-version-1-2.aspx
to implement this but it does not seem to work for me.

```
<div class="container">
        <ng-view class="slide-animation"></ng-view></div>
        </div>
```

and I added the css given in the link in my css file

```
slide-animation.ng-enter, .slide-animation.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;

  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  min-height:1000px;
}

.slide-animation.ng-enter {
  opacity:0;
  left:100px;
}

.slide-animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  left:0;
  opacity:1;
}

.slide-animation.ng-leave {
  left:0;
  opacity:1;
}

.slide-animation.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  left:-100px;
  opacity:0;
}
```

But I am not able to slide my view. I did not add the 'ngAnimate' directive. Is this right approach to get views to slide for navigation.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show your module creation, but you need to include `ngAnimate` as a submodule (which is in a separate js file - `angular-animate.js`):

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);
```

Comment: Also, include the Javascript file. <script src="angular-animate.js"></script>

Comment: Thought that was obvious, but I adapted my answer.

Comment: It should be, but if user3339128 is quite new, he might not know since early AngularJS did not require the individual inclusions, include route.